# opengl : glGetTexImage for 2d textures and 1d texture array confusion

Tags: java, opengl, textures

For texture2D i extract the texture for an mipmap as follows

```
pixels=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*width*height);
    
GL11.glGetTexImage(
                    GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,mipMap
                   ,GL11.GL_RGB,GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
                   ,pixels
                  );
```

As per the documentation it writes 4 bytes per pixels setting the required components to zero if the texture is not 4 components.

Later i can create an 2D texture using the pixels as follows

```
GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4); //4 bytes since RGBA bytes were read from texture

GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0
                 ,GL11.GL_RGB,width,height,0
                 ,GL11.GL_RGB,GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);
```

So this works perfectly for 2D textures.

Now jump to texture 1D Arrays i read the images for all layers of an specific mipmap as follows

```
pixels=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*image.width*layers); //again creating RGBA byte buffer because thats the default behaviour

GL11.glGetTexImage(                                     //this will return the texture images of all layers of mipmap level 0
                   GL30.GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,0
                  ,GL11.GL_RGB,GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
                  ,pixels
                 );

ByteBuffer levelN=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*image.width);

int offset=4*image.width*level;                         //level is layer 0,layer 1 so on this part reads only the texels of an specific layer
for(int i=offset;i<offset+(image.width*4);i++){levelN.put(pixels.get(i));}

pixels=levelN;
```

But later when i create my texture1D array as follows

```
ByteBuffer[] layers=//read using above method

 GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4); //4 bytes since RGBA bytes were read from texture

GL11.glTexImage2D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,0                                //allocate enough storage for all layers
                 ,GL11.GL_RGB,width,layers.length,0
                 ,GL11.GL_RGB,GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,(ByteBuffer)null);



for(int layer=0;i<layers.length;layer++)
{
 ByteBuffer image=layers[i];
 
 GL11.glTexSubImage2D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,0                              //Update individual layers using texSubImage
                      ,0,layer,width,1
                      ,GL11.GL_RGB,GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image);
}
```

The Colors come out all *incorrect* and even changing the texture format to GL_RGBA also didn't solve the problem.but when i change the constant from 4 to 3[read only 3 bytes per pixel in the readMethod() of texture 1d array] everything works correctly again. So i am really confused  here because all my test textures are RGB format and what i observed was

->For 2D Textures reading 4 bytes per pixel in glGetTexImage() but then later specifying only RGB for the texture format worked

->For 1D Texture Arrays reading 3 bytes per pixel in the glGetTexImage() but then later specifying only RGB for texture format worked

But the [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) say that it default reads 4 bytes per pixel for all texture types unless you the change that behaviour using pixelStorei()

and i am only using that method for creating 2D textures not anywhere else.

Can someone please explain why the diffrences?

Comment: **"As per the documentation it writes 4 bytes per pixels "* - No it does not. `glGetTexImage(...GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE...)` reads 3 bytes per pixel. The length of a line is aligned to 4 bytes (if `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is 4).

Comment: But is says that it fills out the alpha to zero if the texture is RGB format right?Even then why did 4 bytes work for my tex2D even though it was an RGB texture?

Comment: It says: *"If the selected texture image does not contain four components [...]"*. That means if you try to read an RGB texture to an RGBA target buffer, the alpha channel will be set 255. The arguments to `glGetTexImage` do not specify the format of the source texture, but they specify the format of the target buffer.

Comment: I see but I specified unpack allignment to 4 for my 1D texture array[forgot to include in my question] and it did nothing. My buffer is RGBA and my allignment is also 4 now but that didn't solve anything

Comment: In a 1D texture 1 line is the entire texture. If you would have a 1xN 2D texture, then the length of  a line would be 1 pixel.

Comment: So how do we specify 4 byte alignment for 1D texture The same way we did for 3D textures using unpack allignment cause that method doesn't work for 1d textures or arrays

Comment: Read it to an GL_RGBA target or use a 1xN 2D texture.

Comment: But I did read it to an GL_RGBA target[My byte buffer which has 4 components]and it didn't work. 1N 2D textures would be rather expensive though

Comment: Anyway I will try playing around with the buffer a little more tomorrow and will edit the results in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per the documentation it writes 4 bytes per pixels [...]

No it does not. [`glGetTexImage(...GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) reads 3 bytes per pixel. The length of a line is aligned to 4 bytes (if `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is 4).
The arguments *format* and _type of `glGetTexImage` do not specify the format of the source texture, but the format of the target buffer.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try and let you know. I have only used UNPACK ALLIGNMENT but not  PACK ALLIGNMENT maybe thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes you were right again. Just as i needed to specify unpack allignment for creating my texture using glTexImage2D ,I needed to specify pack allignment to read the same pixels from my texture and when i specified pack allignment as 1 for both my texture2D and 1DArray i was correctly able to read the pixels from both using only a 3 component bytebuffer. Before i wrap this up Is there a way to decipher the allignment of an texture using it's width and numOfComponents per pixel rather than specifying  1 everywhere which i heard has a performace hit from reading previous threads?

Comment: @Syncit You cannot specify the alignment per pixel. The size of a pixel depends only on the target format and type.

Comment: I understand, well anyway i specify alignment 1 for RGB and 4 for RGBA textures and it seems to work for most general cases. Thats all i  have to ask, thanks again